# Help with formatting numbers, objective-c

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

I have the following,

`int intMilliseconds = rawSplit % 1000;`

which returns the milliseconds left from a time that i have entered, however it in very few cases returns three number (###) instead of the usual two (##).

How might i get it to always return two numbers? (##)

Any help would be great thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's going to be a three-digit number any time `rawSplit` is a number between x,099 and x,999. The modulo operator `%` gives you the remainder after dividing by the right-hand operand. If you perform `1064 % 1000`, the result is `64`. If you perform `1548 % 1000`, the result is `548`.

You can change the information you're getting -- performing modulo 100, for example: `1064 % 100 -> 64` and `1548 % 100 -> 48` -- but you can't make this expression "return" two digits all the time.

From [my comment below](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7311829/help-with-formatting-numbers-objective-c/7311892#comment-8812889):

I guess you could use "centiseconds"; just divide your milliseconds by ten and drop the fractional part.

Comment: nuts, is it possible to trim the number to two digits if it's three?

Comment: Can you explain what your goal is? I don't really understand.

Comment: well i end up with a number like this 02:23:02 (min:sec:milli) almost all of the time with my current code, and each piece of it is entered in separately. so it figures out minutes, then seconds and then milliseconds, and I just format the numbers to look like min:sec:milli, but with the milli I want to only show two numbers, never three.

Comment: @James: How do you trim a number like 0.934 into two digits except by rounding? How do you trim a number like 934 into two digits at all? There are 1000 milliseconds in a second, there is nothing that can be done about that.

Comment: @James: There's a thousand milliseconds in a second, by definition. A large portion of those thousand numbers have three digits. I guess you could convert to centiseconds (which isn't really a thing that anyone uses); divide your milliseconds by ten and drop the fractional part.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like what you want to do is truncate your milliseconds to hundredths of a second. You could do something like this:

```
int hundredths= (int)( (float)intMilliseconds / 10.0f ) * 10;
```

Here, for example, 934 or 939 milliseconds will come out as 93 hundredths of a second.

By the way, your phrasing is a little odd - there's really no way to 'format' a number of milliseconds (from 0 to 999) as a two-digit number. Because your format is `xx:xx:xx`, I'm assuming you mean you want to display hundredths of a second.